# Replacing Part of InnerText in XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm writing a program in VB using visual studio 2010. I'm trying to replace text in an xml but I'm not sure how I can do this.

My xml file looks like this. There are tags with the same name but in different level.

```
<root>
    //1st example
    <tagA> //outer
        <nameA>something</nameA>
        <tagA>
           <flagA>%replace001%</flagA>
           <flagB>Keep this</flagB>
        </tagA> //inner
    </tagA>
    <tagB>
        some other stuff
    </tagB>
    //2nd example
    <tagA>
        %raplace002%
    </tagA>
</root>
```

I'm trying to replace the values in surrounded by `%`, and those are guarenteed under `tagA`

I wrote my code like this:

```
replaceList = {"%replace001", "%replace002%"}
For Each str in replaceList
    For Each node in xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("tagA")
        node.InnerText = node.InnerText.Replace(str, "success")
    Next
Next
```

But this caused an issue in the 1st example where it's getting the outter part of the section but not the inner part, which makes the `Replace` not entirely what I'm looking for.

Can someone help me with this? I basically want to replace the most inner inntertext only.

Note: I'm using `XmlDocument`, please don't provide answers such as converting the whole xml to String and do simple String.Replace.

Thank you!

Edit:

Sorry I didn't make it clear enough.

There are more children in `tagA`, and `tagA` could be a child of another `tagA`.

I'm looking for more most inner `tagA`, but it doesn't always mean that it has no children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only inner most `<tagA>`, you can use `SelectNodes()` method passing the following XPath as parameter :

```
//tagA[not(.//tagA)]
```

Above XPath means select, all `<tagA>` elements, anywhere in the document, which doesn't have any other `<tagA>` child element. Change the inner for each loop to be as follow :

```
For Each node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//tagA[not(.//tagA)]")
    node.InnerText = node.InnerText.Replace(str, "success")
Next
```

Comment: sorry I didn't make it clear enough, please see my edit.